# How do I "print" something to the console in pylons?

Tags: python, django, console, pylons

```
paster serve --reload development.ini
```

..for debug = true

THis is what I do to load a development server for Pylons.

However, when I do:

```
print "hello world"
```

THis message doesn't print out in the console. In Django, it does.

Comment: Where are you doing the print?

When I try this in a controller method, the text I printed appears on the console just fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Pylons **[logging package](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html)** is **the** method to perform logging:

```
import logging
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
log.debug('hello world')
```

This will work as long as you have logging setup **[configured correctly](http://pylonsbook.com/en/1.1/logging.html#introducing-logging-configuration)** in your development.ini. I think the code above should be sufficient without any modifications to default configuration. In case it isn't  you can call **log.info**, **log.warn**, **log.error** or **log.critical** instead of **log.debug** for your message to pass through.

I highly recommend reading [this chapter](http://pylonsbook.com/en/1.1/logging.htm) of [Pylons Book](http://pylonsbook.com/).